# I can't seem to center <section>

Tags: html, css

The strange thing is, I didn't change anything but when I refreshed the page the element was shifted over to the left.
my code is:

```
<section class='gallery-set'>
  <div>
    <img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'>
  </div>
</section>
```

and my css for the `gallery-set` class is simply:

```
.gallery-set {
    background-color:#447684;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width:500px;
    height:700px;
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I honestly have no clue why it is shifted to the left despite me setting the margin to auto, especially since this has worked before.

Comment: `margin:auto` doesn't necessarily mean centered. It means the browser will supply a value for you. Many times that's `0` or some other low number, but it doesn't have to mean centered.

Comment: To follow up on my earlier comment: `margin:auto` *will* get you horizontal centering in many contexts, but only if you don't interfere with it by, for example, using `display:inline-block` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some ways:

**Put a div and use text-align**

CSS:

```
.align {text-align: center;}
.gallery-set{
background-color:#447684;
border-radius:5px;
border: 2px solid black;
width:500px;
height:700px;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

`<div class="align"><section class='gallery-set'><div>
<img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'></div></section></div>`

**Use margin: auto and display: block**

CSS:

```
.gallery-set{
background-color:#447684;
border-radius:5px;
border: 2px solid black;
width:500px;
height:700px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
```

HTML:

`<section class='gallery-set'><div>
<img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'></div></section>`

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. However, do you know why simply setting the margin to auto did not work in this case where it has worked many times before?

Comment: @nachime remove `display: inline-block;` see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QRE8S/

Comment: If you are using display: inline-block, the div is not aligned with the margin: auto. You need to use the first step that i said to align using inline-block (put a div and use text-align).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display:inline-block;` and it will work. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/QesEM/).

You may have meant to use `display:block` instead, which would make sense. Using `inline-block` doesn't make sense if you want to center the `<section>`. See [this page](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) for a good demonstration of how the various `display` values work.